# I can't get VSCode to show me function names in the breadcrumbs / outline in c/c++ files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-navigation

I'm on os 10.11.6 and using VSCode Version: 1.47.3

I've got PlatformIO and C/C++ extensions installed.  I've been programming microcontrollers for a few years with this setup.  One day I noticed that the breadcrumbs were showing up with the functions listed and everything.  It was great to be able to navigate around a file by selecting a function from a list.  Then one day is stopped showing up and I have no idea why.  I've tried disabling extensions and re-installing them but I can not get the outline view or breadcrumbs to list out the functions located in my c/c++ files.  In the outline pane is just says "No Symbols Found in Document".  It seems to work fine for .json files but not for C/C++ files.  Has anyone had this problem?  There are a many posts from a couple of years ago where a "new" version of vscode supposedly fixed the issue but I've still got the problem.  Could it be a problem with the clang not working ?

Date: 2020-07-23T13:08:29.692Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 15.6.0

Comment: Well it started working for about 4 days, and then it stopped again.  The outline view was working but it was also giving all kinda of errors about not being able to find include files even though it was compiling and building fine.  Then I renamed the main folder to remove the space in the name and everything stopped working again. ;(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by accident because the platformio system stopped being able to install libraries.  I uninstalled the platformio extension in vscode.  Then deleted the ~/.platformio directory,  re-installed platformio in vscode and now it works !

Comment: Now it stopped working again and my previous solution doesn't fix it . . . GRRRRRR.

Comment: Ok, maybe it was just a system restart I needed.